# Print Crystal Report without converting to pdf in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I want to to print my Crystal Report without converting to .pdf. When user clicks on print button, it simply open print view of browser.

Comment: Did you simply try: <<< CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = ReportDocument1; >>> This should open the report in the browser directly (inside CrystalReportViewer). If you are having trouble with existing code, please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try THis code for directly export in to the .pdf file.......

```
   ExportOptions CrExportOptions ;
                    DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
                    PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
                    CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "c:\\csharp.net-informations.pdf";
                    CrExportOptions = doc.ExportOptions;
                    {
                        CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                        CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                        CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                        CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
                    }
                    doc.Export();
```

instead of `c:\\csharp.net-informations.pdf` set your path where you want to save the pdf file